# Simple inequality proof in analysis

Tags: analysis, inequality, proof-verification

Just need verification on whether my proof is valid. I couldn't find a straightforward way to prove this inequality directly, so I tried a proof by contradiction instead.

The question: Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$. Prove that if $a - \epsilon < b$  for every $\epsilon > 0$, then $a \le b$.

My proof:
Suppose $a > b$. Let $a = 1, b = 0$. Then we can find $\epsilon = 1 > 0$ such that $a - \epsilon = 0 \not < b = 0$. This is a contradiction. Therefore by the Trichotomy Law of real numbers, $a \le b$.

Comment: There doesn't seem like there's much to prove based on what you're allowed to assume. Simple implications and strength of relations should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your proof is not correct. Just proceed by contradiction: if $a>b$, then you can choose $\varepsilon=a-b$ and deduce that $a-(a-b)<b$, i.e. $b<b$. Contradiction, therefore $a \leq b$.

Comment: Could you explain why my proof isn't correct?

Comment: Because you are not allowed to reduce to a numerical case like $a=1$ and $b=0$. You should produce a proof that works with any admissible choice of the parameters. In other words, you proved only a particular case, but the general case is still open.

Comment: But with one numerical example I have shown that it is not possible to claim $a > b$ because there exists at least one counterexample

Comment: No. You just proved that $1>0$, which is rather clear... You tried to prove a theorem by showing that it is indeed correct in a single case, and this is not enough.

Comment: I proved that if $a > b$, then there exists some $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb R$ for which $a - \epsilon < b$ does not hold for every $\epsilon$. I don't see how I just proved that 1 > 0, sorry but I'm quite slow when it comes to proofs...

Comment: OKay, let me write down the entire process so that it is easier to "debug". 
First I assume that the premise is true, i.e. $a - \epsilon < b$ is true for every $\epsilon > 0$. 
Then I suppose that $a > b$. 
I find an example which contradicts the premise. Therefore I cannot claim that $a > b$, so it must be the case that $a \le b$. 

EDIT: Okay, I think I'm starting to see the problem now. I only showed that the theorem is false for one case of $a > b$. But I must show that is false for all $a > b$ in order to claim that is true for all $a \le b$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you must prove that is it always false if $a>b$.